# Multiple Function Apps not getting deployed

Tags: azure-functions

I have three function apps in my solution as shown below:

[image]

I created the build & release steps to deploy these 3 function apps to the same app service plan. On running the build, it created the artifact with these function app solutions in zip:

[image]

and I see these function apps being deployed:

[image]

On clicking the function app, I see a function in one of the function apps but not in the other two.

[image]

What am I missing? Please let me know if you need more details. Thank you!

UPDATE:

Build steps:

```
# Function xxx
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'dotnet publish xxx Function'
      inputs:
        command: publish
        arguments: '--configuration Release --output publish_output'
        projects: 'Service/WebApi/Service/Hosts.xxxFunction/*.csproj'
        publishWebProjects: false
        modifyOutputPath: false
        zipAfterPublish: false

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'archive xxx Function files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output"
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Hosts.xxxFunction.zip"

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'publish xxx Function files'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Hosts.xxxFunction.zip'
        ArtifactName: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
# End xxx Function
```

Release steps:

```
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  displayName: 'Deploy ${{ parameters.name }} function app'  
  inputs:
    appType: 'functionapp'
    azureSubscription: ${{parameters.serviceConnection}}
    appName: '${{ parameters.solutionAbbreviation }}-compute-fa-${{ parameters.environmentAbbreviation }}-${{ parameters.name }}'
    Package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(Build.BuildNumber)/Hosts.${{ parameters.name }}.zip'
    deploymentMethod: 'auto'
    resourceGroupName: '${{ parameters.solutionAbbreviation }}-${{ parameters.environmentAbbreviation }}'
```

Comment: Please post your release pipeline details.

Comment: Please see updated question.

Comment: you can check 2 things now. First you can check if the files actually made it there using Kudu (go to funcname.scm.azurewebsites.net). 
Another possible problem could be that your function is not configured properly and the host is not properly starting in the cloud. You can check in diagnostics/logs UI

Answer (score 0):

Deploy azure function have two steps:

**1, Create azure function app on azure.**

After this step, you can see the function app on azure, but this doesn't mean you have deploy the function. It just means the corressponding function app container is been prepared.

**2, Upload the content of function app to the function app container.**

You can use some deployment method like zip deploy to deploy your function app:

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g yourresourcegroupname -n yourfunctionappnameonazure --src <zip_file_path>
```

This is the doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#cli

Another thing to notice, sometimes azure portal doesn't show the function doesn't mean the function not been deployed. You can go to `https://yourfunctionappnameonazure.scm.azurewebsites.net/`, then go to `D:\home\site\wwwroot>`.(This is the physical directory of azure function app, if this place don't have function files, then that means you deploy failed. Sometimes azure portal doesn't show anything but function already been deployed.)